# .htaccess rewrite rule for particular URL segment

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am writing the rewrite rule `myweb.com`.

My **requirement** is this :

`myweb.com/da-da` should be redirected to `myweb.dk/da-da`

and

`myweb.com/da-da/any_url_segment` should be redirected to `myweb.dk/da-da/any_url_segment`

Please suggest how I can write a rewrite rule for this in .htaccess?

Comment: You don't provide enough information. Are `myweb.com` and `myweb.dk` pointing to the same domain (and so, the same htaccess) ? Is your rule for everything or only for `da-da` path (and everything following it) ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `.htaccess` file on myweb.com:

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://myweb.dk/$1 [R=301]
```

Change 301 to 302 if you don't want the redirect to be permanent.

Comment: Oops... Answered too quickly. Fixed.